# Mixing Java NIO with IO input streams read operation

Tags: java, sockets, io, nio

I need to use NIO to allow the server side to support timeout on write operations, but handling reading operations on the socket channels complicates my program.

I was wondering if it's possible to write to the sockets using NIO but to read using regular IO, something like

```
((SocketChannel) selectedKey.channel()).socket().getInputStream().read(buffer)
```

Will this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can only use streams on the channel socket if the channel is in blocking mode, in which case you wouldn't have a SelectionKey.

Comment: Ah well, I guess I'm stuck with doing it the "hard" way ;)